# Need help in Downloading postman rest client for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, postman

I am trying to download postman rest client for chrome,from the following sites

**Chrome web store**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

http://www.getpostman.com/

I  am getting  following error in a pop up :

An error has occurred ,Network - failed - with reload and close buttons.

My System configurations : Windows 7 , Service Pack , 64 Bit OS , 3 GB RAM .

I have tried multiple times to download it. But i am getting same error pop up each time. 
can anyone please help me in sorting  this out. Thank you.